# Rails uploading multiple photos onto Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I currently use the Paperclip gem to attach photos onto certain models in my project. However, I have a blog model where I use multiple photos per instance of the blog.

I'm looking for a solution where I can just upload photos into a folder on Amazon S3 and refer to these photos later using the HTML anchor tags. I don't want to attach the photos to any model.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this myself, but I would look for the solution here http://amazon.rubyforge.org/ I believe paperclip uses it behind the hood.